# How to write a Dockerfile depends on other images

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, netty

I have a Spring Boot application which runs a netty connection waiting on port "1883" for incoming connections. It is working perfectly when I run in locally with "java -jar app.jar" file and I can connect to in. I want to Dockerize this application. 
I this application depends on redis, mongodb and I provided them on docker-compose file as follows. When I run `"docker-compose up --build"` it runs successfully but I can not connect to it with telnet or any client.

telnet 0.0.0.0 1883                                                                                                                                                 Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

```
version: '3.4'
networks:
  front:
  back:
services:

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis
    networks:
      - back
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: springboot-mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mqtt:
    build: .
    restart: always
    image: mqtt:latest
    container_name: "mqtt"
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://springboot-mongo/mqtt
      - MQTT_REDIS_HOST=redis
      - MQTT_REDIS_PORT=6379
      - MQTT_REDIS_DATABASE=redis
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
```

And the following Dockerfile is for this Spring Boot application as follows.

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
VOLUME /tmp
RUN mkdir log
RUN touch log/spring.log
RUN mkdir /opt/metao
ADD build/libs/mqtt.jar mqtt.jar
COPY build/libs/mqtt.jar mqtt.jar
EXPOSE 1883
RUN sh -c 'touch /mqtt.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://springboot-mongo/mqtt","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","./mqtt.jar"]
```

The output when running `"docker-compose"` is as follows:

```
mqtt    |
mqtt    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
mqtt    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
mqtt    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
mqtt    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
mqtt    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
mqtt    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
mqtt    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)
mqtt    |
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:03.879  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.metao.mqtt.MqttApplication           : Starting MqttApplication on 6eedaea3ae42 with PID 1 (/mqtt.jar started by root in /)
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:03.885  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.metao.mqtt.MqttApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:05.989  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:06.617  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 608ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:07.304  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: public void com.metao.mqtt.server.TCPServerAcceptorHandler.initialize() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
mqtt    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
mqtt    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.redisson.misc.URIBuilder (jar:file:/mqtt.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/redisson-3.7.2.jar!/) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
mqtt    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.redisson.misc.URIBuilder
mqtt    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
mqtt    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:08.001  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.redisson.Version                     : Redisson 3.7.2
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:09.172  INFO 1 --- [isson-netty-1-3] o.r.c.pool.MasterConnectionPool          : 32 connections initialized for redis/192.168.16.3:6379
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:09.186  INFO 1 --- [isson-netty-1-4] o.r.c.pool.MasterPubSubConnectionPool    : 1 connections initialized for redis/192.168.16.3:6379
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:09.962  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[springboot-mongo:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:10.199  INFO 1 --- [oot-mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:2}] to springboot-mongo:27017
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:10.210  INFO 1 --- [oot-mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=springboot-mongo:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=7538600}
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:11.053  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.m.repositories.SubscriptionsStore    : init invoked
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:11.305  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.mqtt.redisson.RedissonSessionsStore  : retrieveAllSubscriptions returning subs []
**mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:11.405  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.metao.mqtt.utils.MqttFactoryBuilder  : Server bound host:localhost, port: 1883
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:12.093  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.metao.mqtt.MqttApplication           : Started MqttApplication in 9.196 seconds (JVM running for 10.678)**
mqtt    | 2019-12-20 16:44:12.207  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:3}] to springboot-mongo:27017
```

If you see the output the docker says that the application is up and running on port **1883** and in **localhost** but the problem is that I can not connect to it. I would happy if someone could help me.

The out put after running `telnet localhost:1883`

```
telnet 0.0.0.0 1883                                                                                                                                                 Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: try to run this `telnet 127.0.0.1 1883` (without colon in between ip and port)